# ASP.NET Core 2.1 Web application with React.Aspnet error when running as Docker application

Tags: asp.net, reactjs, docker, asp.net-core

I have a ASP.NET Core 2.1 web application with React.aspnet. It runs perfectly when running in IIS. But when I run it in Docker, the application can still run successfully but the view page with React failed with following error:

```
  fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
React.TinyIoC.TinyIoCResolutionException: Unable to resolve type: React.ReactEnvironment ---> React.TinyIoC.TinyIoCResolutionException: Unable to resolve type: React.JavaScriptEngineFactory ---> JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.Core.JsEngineLoadException: Failed to create instance of the ChakraCoreJsEngine. Most likely it happened, because the 'libChakraCore.so' assembly or one of its dependencies was not found. Try to install the JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.ChakraCore.Native.linux-x64 package via NuGet. ---> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared library 'ChakraCore' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the LD_DEBUG environment variable: libChakraCore: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
   at JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.ChakraCore.JsRt.NativeMethods.JsCreateRuntime(JsRuntimeAttributes attributes, JsThreadServiceCallback threadService, JsRuntime& runtime)
   at JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.ChakraCore.ChakraCoreJsEngine.<>c__DisplayClass10_1.<.ctor>b__0()
   at JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.ChakraCore.ScriptDispatcher.<>c__DisplayClass11_0.<Invoke>b__0()
   at JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.ChakraCore.ScriptDispatcher.StartThread()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.ChakraCore.ScriptDispatcher.InnnerInvoke(Func`1 del)
   at JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.ChakraCore.ScriptDispatcher.Invoke(Action action)
   at JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.ChakraCore.ChakraCoreJsEngine..ctor(ChakraCoreSettings settings)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.ChakraCore.ChakraCoreJsEngine..ctor(ChakraCoreSettings settings)
   at JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.ChakraCore.ChakraCoreJsEngineFactory.CreateEngine()
   at JSPool.JsPool`2.CreateEngine()
   at JSPool.JsPool`2.PopulateEngines()
   at JSPool.JsPool`2..ctor(JsPoolConfig`1 config)
   at React.JavaScriptEngineFactory.CreatePool()
   at React.JavaScriptEngineFactory..ctor(IJsEngineSwitcher jsEngineSwitcher, IReactSiteConfiguration config, ICache cache, IFileSystem fileSystem)
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object[] )
   at React.TinyIoC.TinyIoCContainer.ConstructType(Type requestedType, Type implementationType, ConstructorInfo constructor, NamedParameterOverloads parameters, ResolveOptions options)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at React.TinyIoC.TinyIoCContainer.ConstructType(Type requestedType, Type implementationType, ConstructorInfo constructor, NamedParameterOverloads parameters, ResolveOptions options)
   at React.TinyIoC.TinyIoCContainer.SingletonFactory.GetObject(Type requestedType, TinyIoCContainer container, NamedParameterOverloads parameters, ResolveOptions options)
   at React.TinyIoC.TinyIoCContainer.ResolveInternal(TypeRegistration registration, NamedParameterOverloads parameters, ResolveOptions options)
   at React.TinyIoC.TinyIoCContainer.ConstructType(Type requestedType, Type implementationType, ConstructorInfo constructor, NamedParameterOverloads parameters, ResolveOptions options)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at React.TinyIoC.TinyIoCContainer.ConstructType(Type requestedType, Type implementationType, ConstructorInfo constructor, NamedParameterOverloads parameters, ResolveOptions options)
   at React.TinyIoC.TinyIoCContainer.CustomObjectLifetimeFactory.GetObject(Type requestedType, TinyIoCContainer container, NamedParameterOverloads parameters, ResolveOptions options)
   at React.TinyIoC.TinyIoCContainer.ResolveInternal(TypeRegistration registration, NamedParameterOverloads parameters, ResolveOptions options)
   at React.TinyIoC.TinyIoCContainer.Resolve[ResolveType]()
   at React.AspNet.BabelFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Have tried many solution but it doesn't work. My nuget packages look like the following:

[image]

My Dockerfile looks like the following:

```
    FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.1 AS build
WORKDIR /app

EXPOSE 80

# copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.sln .
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# copy everything else and build app
COPY . ./
WORKDIR /app

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends apt-utils
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | bash - && apt-get install -yq nodejs build-essential
RUN npm install -g npm
RUN npm install 

RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o ./out

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.1 AS runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app/out ./
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "app.dll"]
```

Can anyone give some tips about what the problem could be?

Comment: Looking at the error looks like you are trying to create linux based container and it is failing  with error`Failed to create instance of the ChakraCoreJsEngine. Most likely it happened, because the 'libChakraCore.so' assembly or one of its dependencies was not found. Try to install the JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.ChakraCore.Native.linux-x64 package via NuGet`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to fix the issue by installing different OS-specific versions of **JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.ChakraCore**.

```
<PackageReference Include="JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.ChakraCore.Native.linux-x64" Version="3.0.9" />
<PackageReference Include="JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.ChakraCore.Native.win-x64" Version="3.0.9" />
<PackageReference Include="JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.ChakraCore.Native.win-x86" Version="3.0.9" />
<PackageReference Include="JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.ChakraCore.Native.osx-x64" Version="3.0.9" />
```

According to the [wiki page](https://github.com/Taritsyn/JavaScriptEngineSwitcher/wiki/ChakraCore) for ChakraCore:

> This package does not contain the native implementations of
>   ChakraCore. Therefore, you need to choose and install the most
>   appropriate package(s) for your platform.

By installing all versions, anyone pulled this package can run and build docker image on different OS without worrying about package dependency again.